# Add pdf metadata with accents in python

Tags: python, pdf

I want to change the metadata of the pdf file using this code:

```
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileReader, PdfFileWriter

title = "Vice-présidence pour l'éducation"
fin = open(filename, 'rb')
reader = PdfFileReader(fin)
writer = PdfFileWriter()
writer.appendPagesFromReader(reader)
metadata = reader.getDocumentInfo()

metadata.update({'/Title':title})

writer.addMetadata(metadata)

fout = open(filename, 'wb')
writer.write(fout)

fin.close()
fout.close()
```

It works fine if the title is in english(no accents) but when it has accents I get the following error:

```
TypeError: createStringObject should have str or unicode arg
```

How can I add a title with accent to the metadata ?

Thank you

Comment: I can't reproduce this.  What are you're versions of python and pypdf2? (`python -c 'import sys, PyPDF2; print(sys.version_info, PyPDF2.__version__)'`)

Comment: @snakecharmerb `sys.version_info(major=3, minor=6, micro=2, releaselevel='final', serial=0) 1.26.0` and Python 3.6.2

Comment: @snakecharmerb What is your version of python and pypdf2 ?

Comment: Tested on `sys.version_info(major=3, minor=7, micro=0, releaselevel='final', serial=0) 1.26.0` and `sys.version_info(major=3, minor=6, micro=0, releaselevel='final', serial=0) 1.26.0`, on Linux.

Comment: I also can't reproduce this, tested with `sys.version_info(major=3, minor=4, micro=3, releaselevel='final', serial=0) 1.26.0` on Ubuntu 14.04. `PyPDF2==1.26.0`

Comment: Can you please check that code you posted here is exactly the same as the one you execute? And can you please check the file encoding of your saved .py file, for example with `file -I program.py`

Comment: @Merlin1896 I found the problem it is because I'm using Jupyter notebook

Comment: Could you please try to add these two lines to your `.bash_profile` file: `export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8` and `export LANG=en_US.UTF-8`, then reload the profile with `source ~/.bash_profile` and then start a new notebook `ipython notebook`. See if you still have problems.

Comment: @Merlin1896 I already have them

Comment: Can't reproduce it either in Jupyter Notebook, sys.version_info(major=3, minor=6, micro=5, releaselevel='final', serial=0), PyPDF2 version 1.26.0, on Windows 7

Answer (score 3):

The only way to get this error message is to have the wrong type for the parameter `string` in the `createStringObject(string)`-function in the [library](https://github.com/mstamy2/PyPDF2/blob/1.26.0/PyPDF2/generic.py#L300) itself.

It's looking for type string or bytes using these functions in [utils.py](https://github.com/mstamy2/PyPDF2/blob/1.26.0/PyPDF2/utils.py#L46)

```
import builtins
bytes_type = type(bytes()) # Works the same in Python 2.X and 3.X
string_type = getattr(builtins, "unicode", str)
```

I can only reproduce your error if I rewrite your code with an obviously wrong type like this (code is rewritten using with statement but only the commented line is important):

```
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileReader, PdfFileWriter


with open(inputfile, "rb") as fr, open(outputfile, "wb") as fw:
    reader = PdfFileReader(fr)
    writer = PdfFileWriter()

    writer.appendPagesFromReader(reader)
    metadata = reader.getDocumentInfo()

    # metadata.update({'/Title': "Vice-présidence pour l'éducation"})
    metadata.update({'/Title': [1, 2, 3]})  # <- wrong type here !
    writer.addMetadata(metadata)

    writer.write(fw)
```

It seems that the type of your string `title = "Vice-présidence pour l'éducation"` is not matching to whatever `bytes_type` or `string_type` is resolved. Either you have a weird type of the title variable (which I cannot see in your code, maybe because of creating a MCVE) or you have trouble getting `bytes_type` or `string_type` as types intended by library writer (this can be a bug in the library or an erroneous installation, hard to tell for me).

Without reproducible code, it's hard to provide a solution. But hopefully this will give you the right direction to go. Maybe it's enough to set the type of your string to whatever `bytes_type` or `string_type` is resolved to. Other solutions would be on library site or simply hacks.